# How to install wkhtmltopdf for Odoo in a raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to install Odoo in a Raspberry Pi 4 (with raspberry pi OS). Odoo documentation sais that

"wkhtmltopdf is not installed through pip and must be installed manually in version 0.12.5 for it to support headers and footers. See our wiki for more details on the various versions."

But there is not a version for the ARM architecture. There is "Source code" version at "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/tag/0.12.5"

How can I install wkhtmltopdf from that Source code version in my Raspberry Pi?